# Route-Me \ CloudMade dragging problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cloudmade, route-me

I'm using CloudMade on iPhone and I've got this really critical issue to solve.

The problem is when the user moves the map up\down there is nothing to stop him when he gets to the end of the map. 
This way he can move the map forever and just see a gray view.

How can I prevent the user from dragging the map when he got to its end?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer in CloudMade is currently working on this issue. It will be fixed during Autumn, also please take a look at [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/route-me-map/browse_thread/thread/0c98507cc37bb5ac/2bd9d243923ce23f?lnk=raot&pli=1) at google groups.